# My Win JS SQLite 3 application takes too much time to do inserts

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-runtime, winjs, winrt-async

Here I am making app of Sqlite3 database in Windows store apps in HTML /java script.

Right now I am using Sqlite3-WinRT component.

Its working fine but I am not getting required performance. Its taking too much time for insertion data. **Is there any way to make the insert performance faster with this library?**

If this is not possible, can any one can suggest me any other library or component for using sqlite3 in Windows store apps??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you can use sqlite-net which LinqTOSQL so you can get better performance there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10894948/2963912

Comment: I have used SQLite3-WinRT Component I am asking for performance enhancement.So need other Wrapper.

Comment: is that compulsory to use SQLite? you can go for indexeddb for HTML5/JS

Comment: Till now i have developed my app in SQLite...so it would be better if I get any help for Sqlite....

Comment: I don't know the equivalent js calls, but did you try wrapping your inserts in a transaction? Related: [Add lots of data to SQLite Database in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671600/add-lots-of-data-to-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @chue x:thanx for your kind help but can you try to give me transaction in js??

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wrap your insertions in a

```
"BEGIN TRANSACTION"
```

and end it with

```
"COMMIT TRANSACTION"
```

, this will certainly improve your insertion (I used same wrapper).

If this doesn't work, you can try to use [this component](https://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/), even if it is in C#, you can use it in WinJS.

There is an [article](http://andywigleyblog.azurewebsites.net/?p=311) on how to improve your insertions and selection using this compoenent.

Answer (score -1):

[Transactions have increased performance in C# SQLite3 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671600/add-lots-of-data-to-sqlite-database-in-c-sharp), so they may help you in your Win JS application.

If you look at [issue 56 in the SQLite3-WinRT issues list](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT/issues/56), they show how to use transactions:

```js
SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath)
.then(function (db) {
  return db.runAsync('PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;');
}).then(function (db) {
  return db.runAsync("BEGIN TRANSACTION;");
});
```

Some notes:

- Issue 56 says that the use of the `PRAGMA` is temporary, and may not be needed in the future. You should test and see if it is needed.
- The code above just starts the transaction. Obviously, you will still need to add: 1) your inserts, and 2) a call to commit or abort the transaction, for example, `db.runAsync("COMMIT TRANSACTION;");`